# Akka actors for java, maven dependency issue

Tags: java, akka

In this official doc they use 2.2-SNAPSHOT version.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html

If try to resolve it - it does not work.

If try to add typesafe repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It does not work neither. 
**Edit:**
Even if I use snapshot repo in "< repository >"

Is there some repo I can use to make official sample working?

If I use previous version, then that example does not resolve some methods (like this: `Props.create`). So I need last one then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the M3?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

If so, please use the above. It's available on the standard Maven repo.

Comment: for my particular case it works. but might not work. I mean official example should be already in repo. kind of this. but yes - thanks for idea to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally people don't publish snapshots to the releases repository (there's almost always a snapshots repository), in Akka's case, it's: **repo.akka.io/snapshots/**

And I definitely recommend to choose one of the timestamped ones and not the snapshot.

Comment: Ok. I see. But then the doc should be updated. what's the sense to mention dependency in doc if impossible to use it. Because even if use snapshot repository there is no needed dependency.

Comment: Note that the documentation is versioned. Look in the documentation for 2.2-M3
http://akka.io/docs/

Comment: ses: You're looking at the _snapshot_ documentation, please refer to this page: http://akka.io/docs/