# How to run akka actors in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, akka

From Akka' site docs:

> This main method will then create the infrastructure needed for
>   running the actors, start the given main actor and arrange for the
>   whole application to shut down once the main actor terminates. Thus
>   you will be able to run the above code with a command similar to the
>   following:
>
> java -classpath  akka.Main example.two.HelloWorld

So, how can I launch it from IntelliJ IDEA? I have not found good/proper Window for that.

Dependecy to AKKA is already in the project:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The code itself (as you can see there is no `main(...)` ) :

```
public class HelloWorld extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        // create the greeter actor
        final ActorRef greeter =
                getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Greeter.class), "greeter");
        // tell it to perform the greeting
        greeter.tell(Greeter.Msg.GREET, getSelf());
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        if (msg == Greeter.Msg.DONE) {
            // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
            getContext().stop(getSelf());
        } else unhandled(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like the documentation and the binary distributions are not in sync.

As you can see [here on Github](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka) the `Main.scala` was added just 16 days ago.

To fix this you can change the dependency version to the `SNAPSHOT` instead. Add the snapshot repository to the pom and change version to `2.2-SNAPSHOT`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>akka-snapshots</id>
            <name>Akka Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now the `akka.Main` will be available. In order to start the application you will have to point to the correct main class and add your own actor class as an argument.

First chose to create a new run configuration:

[image]

Then add a new application:

[image]

Give the application a name (Actor or something) and fill in the main class to be `akka.Main` and add your `HelloWorld` class as `Program Arguments` (remember to include the full package):

[image]

And now you are ready to run the program, just press the play button in the tool bar:

[image]

**Voila!**

Comment: C'est bon. But about SNAPSHOT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569726/akka-actors-for-java-maven-dependency-issue

Comment: @ses Well since you are using the example from the `SNAPSHOT` version then I don't really see the problem. If you want this to work in a stable release then you'll have to wait. At least I answered your question *So, how can I launch it from IntelliJ IDEA?*

Comment: for now I wold be happy to have: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/Main.scala

this class written in java

Comment: Hey @maba I see that in your screenshots, Props.create(Greeter.class) are flagged as error in IntelliJ, but obviously compiling and running thorough sbt command line works. I have exactly the same issue here... Any idea on how to fix that in IntelliJ? It's annoying. :-/

Comment: Any idea how to debug this application in JIdea. Tried the debugger but it does not stop the execution in the break points.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can use the following code to start your actor:

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      akka.Main.main(new String[] { HelloWorld.class.getName() });
  }
}
```