# How to run Akka

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka

It seems like there is no need in a class with a main method in it to be able to run Akka [How to run akka actors in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575081/how-to-run-akka-actors-in-intellij-idea). However, here is what I have:

```
object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(100 seconds)

  import system.dispatcher

  system.scheduler.schedule(1 seconds, 600 seconds) {
    val future = supervisor ? Supervisor.Start
    val list = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[List[Int]]
    supervisor ! list
  }
}
```

I know I have to specify a main method called "akka.Main" in the configuration. But nonetheless, where should I move the current code from `object Application` ?

Comment: Never use Await if you don't have to, and you don't have to. supervisor.tell(Supervisor.Start, supervisor)

Answer (score 5):

You can write something like

```
import _root_.akka.Main
object Application extends App {
  Main.main(Array("somepackage.Supervisor"))
}
```

and Supervisor actor should have overriden preStart function as [@cmbaxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311148/cmbaxter) suggested.

Then run sbt console in intellij and write run.

Comment: Using akka.Main.main() method is quite straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @kdrakon that your code is fine the way it is, but if you wanted to leverage the `akka.Main` functionality, then a simple refactor like so will make things work:

```
package code

class ApplicationActor extends Actor {

  override def preStart = {
    val supervisor = context.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(100 seconds)

    import context.dispatcher

    context.system.scheduler.schedule(1 seconds, 600 seconds) {
      val future = (supervisor ? Supervisor.Start).mapTo[List[Int]]
      val list = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
      supervisor ! list
    }
  }

  def receive = {
    case _ => //Not sure what to do here
  }

}
```

In this case, the `ApplicationActor` is the arg you would pass to `akka.Main` and it would basically be the root supervisor to all other actors created in your hierarchy.  The only fishy thing here is that being an `Actor`, it needs a `receive` implementation and I don't imagine any other actors will be sending messages here thus it doesn't really do anything.  But the power to this approach is that when the `ApplicationActor` is stopped, the stop will also be cascaded down to all other actors that it started, simplifying a graceful shutdown.  I suppose you could have the `ApplicationActor` handle a message to shutdown the actor system given some kind of input (maybe a `ShutdownHookThread` could initiate this) and give this actor some kind of a purpose after all.  Anyway, as stated earlier, your current approach seems fine but this could also be an option if you so desire.

**EDIT**

So if you wanted to run this `ApplicationActor` via `akka.Main`, according to the instructions [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/hello-world.html), you would execute this from your command prompt:

```
java -classpath <all those JARs> akka.Main code.ApplicationActor
```

You will of course need to supply `<all those JARS>` with your dependencies including akka.  At a minimum you will need `scala-library` and `akka-actor` in your classpath to make this run.

Comment: there should be more standard, elegant way to do that. If "receive" is empty, then perhaps, your approach is wrong.

Comment: No, no, an Actor with an empty receive method is completely valid and useful. One important use case is actors with the only purpose of being supervisors.

Comment: can't I move this code to Supervisor instead of ApplicationActor? (which we even won't need to create then).

Comment: `In this case, the ApplicationActor is the arg you would pass to akka.Main ` -- how?

Comment: @MariusKavansky, I updated with info on how to run via `akka.Main`.  In reference to your first comment, yes, you could move this into your supervisor actor if you wanted that actor to be the supervisor for the entire actor hierarchy of your application, thus eliminating the need for `ApplicationActor`.

Comment: @MariusKavansky, I edited my comment after sending to you.  You should be able to run this from ide.  The `akka.Main` class takes a single argument which is the name of the main actor to start up.  So just set up your ide to run `akka.Main` and give it a single program argument of the root actor in your system (your supervisor actor).

Comment: @cmbaxter, why don't you try this code first before sending me? I'm not able to run at least to due 2 reasons: 1) it can't find akka.main (if I use it as an entry point) and thus, I'm not able to run using "run" button 2) there is an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;` -- if I use the standard object Application as an entry point.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/hello-world.html, you'll find that akka.Main expects your root/parent Actor. In your case, Supervisor. As for your already existing code, it can be copied directly into the actors code, possibly in some initialisation calls. For example, refer to the HelloWorld's preStart function.

However, in my opinion, your already existing code is just fine too. Akka.main is a nice helper, as is the microkernel binary. But creating your own main executable is a viable option too.

Comment: I don't understand, what should I do?

Comment: What kdrakon says is that nothing stops you from writing your own normal main method, instantiating an actor system there, and then creating and stopping actors however you want.

Comment: @EndreVarga, would you mind showing me example of it? Do I have to wrap my code inside Application into `def main(Array[String] args)` and that will be it?